# No fields were printed on console after verifying if form is using Acroform or XFA technology?

Tags: java, itext

The "XFA Form" was printed on the console after running the codes, but not the fields. Is there a particular reason why?

Here are the codes :

```
public class VerifyPDFForm {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    String SRC =  "c:/Temp/testCopy.pdf";
    String DEST = "c:/Temp/test10.txt";

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(DEST));
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
    AcroFields form = reader.getAcroFields();
    XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
    System.out.println(xfa.isXfaPresent() ? "XFA form" : "AcroForm");
    Set<String> fields = form.getFields().keySet();
    for (String key : fields) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
    System.out.flush();
    System.out.close();
    reader.close();
}  }
```

Comment: did you check if `fields` is empty?

Comment: It looks like the fields are populated at runtime.  But shouldn't it still print the field regardless of whether it is empty or not?  Really new to Java and IText.

Comment: of course the `fields` are populated at runtime, but if `fields` is empty it will never execute the loop and you are printing the field keys inside the loop.

Comment: If you shared your pdf, we could reproduce and analyse the issue.

Comment: @mkl - unfortunately, it is a company project, so I cannot share it with anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code with some PDFs. You only get fields if you have a pure AcroForm form or a AcroForm/XFA hybrid form, not for a pure XFA form.

This matches a quick code review which reveals that the internal field collection is only filled if there are any AcroForm field definitions.

Thus, concerning your question

> Is there a particular reason why?

... the reason is that the XFA support in iText 5.x is limited and does not include inspecting individual fields in pure XFA forms.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it still possible to fill the fields of a purely dynamic XFA form with data using Java and IText 5.x?  That's my ultimate goal here.

Comment: you can extract the XFA stream using iText, then manipulate ite using the xml API of your choice, and eventually store the XFA xml back into the pdf again with iText.

Comment: I successfully extracted the XML.  The problem was with manipulating the XML.  I could not put in a value/data in a particular text field.

Comment: @InternIII You might want to make that a different question here (How to fill XFA XML with values?); if you cannot share that XML, though, I doubt you will get specific enough answers.